# How to replace prop_map_function to prop_map_inline in \maketitle command

Tags: luatex, expl3

I have a code,which do autotagging of all fields of \maketitle command. This code do iteration via \prop_function,but i want to do it via prop_map_inline,to decrease volume of code,but i get an error:
You can't use a prefix with `the character @'.
Thanks everybody for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true,tagunmarked=false,log/all}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop
  {
    @author = H1 ,
    @date   = H1 ,
    @thanks = H1 ,
    @title  = H1 ,
  }
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[1]{\footnotemark
    \protected@xdef\orig@@thanks{\orig@@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#1}}}
\makeatother
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kozlovskiy_maketitle:
  {
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
      \prop_map_inline:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop{
    \cs_gset_eq:cc { orig@##1 } { ##1 }
    \cs_gset_protected:cpn { ##1 }
      {
        \tagstructbegin{tag=##2}
          \tagmcbegin{tag=##2}
            \use:c { orig@##1 }
          \tagmcend
        \tagstructend
      }
}
\__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle:
    \tagstructend
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle: \maketitle
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \maketitle { \kozlovskiy_maketitle: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\author{alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
\title{test document%
  \thanks{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
  }
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\maketitle
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
Test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're probably missing a `\makeatletter` at the beginning of the code

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Ok,in what place i should use \makeatletter and makeatother,except \thanks command? Why only with function \prop_map_inline happends this issue?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy You only need \makeatletter for the \thanks command. The same issue appears with `\prop_map_function`, so I guess that it appeared for you after switching to `\prop_map_inline` because the `\makeatletter` got lost in the process. (Especially since `\makeatother` is still there)